# Understanding AWS Amplify Pricing: How are request duration and data transfer out related?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I m comfused in AWS amplify.

I have provided [a screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abYv6.png) and what does request duration and data transfer out exactly mean?

Does request duration means the amount of time user spends on the website? like if the user spends 1 hour looking at 1 page, will that charge me $0.20, or is it that, the amount of time it takes to send the frontend files?

Does data transfer out mean that the data transferred to frontend, like the jsx files, or images, is that exactly what data transfer means? Please let me know. Thanks in advance. I m new to AWS, and I'm still in high school, for those reasons, I wasn't really able to understand exactly what it means.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> request duration

It's the time required for amplify to [render the HTML page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/deploy-backend.html).

> data transfer out

Data transferred from Amplify out to requester.

You can use [AWS' Pricing Calculator Estimator](https://calculator.aws/#/estimate) to derive an [approximate pricing](https://calculator.aws/#/estimate?id=954bcf8e3580be275047825a5d5c992d4cb973db).